# Write the content page 'Home' on the code or let the user customize it?

Tags: wordpress

Let's say I have to code the page 'Home' of [this site](http://zoutula.com/themes/kiddie/), what should I do as a programmer? Write the content in the template and if the user needs a modification make him call me or show the content by reading a specific posts of a determined category?
For example, create a category 'slideshow' and loop through it and add as many slides as posts are or a category 'why love us' and do the same?

How senior programmers in WordPress face this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have create one template as you say that will be home, Now if i am a developer for this site , i will divide this i.e.

1. Slider => May use plugin or custom post type.
2. Why Love Us => May be a custom filed is this is fixed in size, or may create custom post type
3. Our Teachers => Will be a custom post type.
4. Courses => Another custom post type
5. Testimonial => Another Custom post type
6. Gallery => It is easy to use plugin or  wordpress built in media gallary
7. Blog => Will be popular or recent post
8. Other general things will be a theme options

So, you can manage your back-end like this so use can easily understood and easy to modify or update content.

Comment: Thanks @Savan, I'm glad to know that my approach wasn't incorrect also, I have just discovered the existence of custom fields in WordPress